# Authenticating users to LDAP after bind with Foxpass

Tags: java, ldap

I've been trying to get a simple snippet of code to run in java - authentication as binder to Foxpass (hosted LDAP service) and then trying to authenticate another user to it.
I basically created a binder in my Foxpass settings and created some users as well.

The code is:

```
Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable <String,String>();
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindUser);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, bindPassword);
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, myFoxpassUrl);

try {
    DirContext ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(env);

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
    controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    controls.setCountLimit(1); 
    controls.setTimeLimit(5000);

    String searchString = "(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=username))";

    results = ldapContext.search("", searchString, controls);

    System.out.println(results.hasMore());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

The binding (authentication with bindUsername and bindPassword works well). However, searching for the users return 0 values. I tried using:

```
sAMAccountName=myusername
sAMAccountName=myusername@mydomain.com
sAMAccountName=CN=myusername,DC=mydomain,DC=com
Or
username=myusername
...
Or
Email=myusername@mydomain.com
```

But nothing seems to work. Any help on finding the right format to do the search.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your searchString once lived in an Active Directory environment.  With Foxbase try

`String searchString = String.format("(uid=%s)", username);`